# Regular expression to convert html class to attribute

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there any way to use regular expression alone or with help of javascript to do the following

from

```
<div class="type-c red blue">
```

to

```
<div type="c" class="red blue">
```

Comment: What is the logic of selecting attributes name from class names?

Comment: OP is trying to refactor some code to this format looks like

Comment: `help of javascript to do the following`. There is a way. Consider using `replaceAll()` with a function as the 2nd param.

Comment: class="type-abc-xyz"  to attribute type="abc-xyz"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regular expression will match what you describe, regardless of the position of "type-xxx" in class attribute

```
/class="([^"]*)type-(\w+)([^"]*)"/g
```

Combining with a string replace

```
let value = '<div class="type-a b">test</div><div class="a type-b">test 2</div>';
value.replace(/class="([^"]*)type-(\w+)([^"]*)"/g, 'type="$2" class="$1$3"');
```

this will yield the result

```
<div type="a" class="b">test</div><div type="b" class="a">test 2</div>
```

Comment: The "regardless of the position" should make this the accepted answer. And that it achieves it thru a regex

Comment: sorry i tried it again. it doesn't work when class="type-ab-cd foo bar", when type-xx contains two dash

Comment: wasnt this just "Accepted"? Ahh i see your comment

Comment: class="([^"]*)type-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)([^"]*)" this works, i'll accept it. i only tweak a little.

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need regular expressions.

(Okay, you do, but only to find the `x` value in `type-x`. Proof [here](https://regex101.com/r/D0ROAM/1).)

You can use a mix of [attribute selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#attribute-selectors), the [data-*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) attribute standard, and the Element[.setAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) method.

Here's an example.

```js
function doChange() {

  // Find all divs with a 'type-x' class
  let myDivs = document.querySelectorAll('div[class*="type-"]');

  myDivs.forEach(curDiv => {

      // Get the specific 'x' for the type
      let curType = /(?<=type-)[A-Za-z\-]+/.exec(curDiv.classList.toString())[0];

      // Set the 'data-type' attribute
      curDiv.setAttribute('data-type', curType);

      // Remove the 'type-x' class
      curDiv.classList.toggle('type-' + curType);

      // Write the 'classList' and 'data-type' attributes for show
      curDiv.innerText = 'classList: ' + curDiv.classList 
                       + '; data-type: ' + curDiv.getAttribute('data-type') + ';';

  });
}
```

```html
<div class="type-a red blue">classList: type-a red blue; data-type: undefined;</div>
<div class="red type-b blue">classList: red type-b blue; data-type: undefined;</div>
<div class="red blue type-c">classList: red blue type-c; data-type: undefined;</div>

<button onclick="doChange()">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: sorry maybe i should state in the question the ask is for code refactoring

Comment: Oh, then I'm obligated to point you at [the famous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). And suggest you consider if your source is consistent and small enough that `regex` is a good choice. If so, you can use the pattern in my answer to help you find the `type-x` classes in the code and start from there.

Comment: I updated the pattern to use positive-lookbehinds (lookaheads) to help you match more easily. They will look for a single character preceded by `type-` so you don't have to worry about taking the first group instead of the match.

Comment: thanks for the help, i found the solution of regex (type-)(.+?)(?="| ) i make use of these two matching group to replace the code

Comment: Can you show that as an answer @FanCheung to your question?

Comment: I ask because I am curious on the exact regex

Comment: still working on it. i get the matching group the hard part to is to do the replace without coding

Comment: Yeah thats what I was wondering on how you achieved it. Perhaps we can combine minds (in @DakotaMethvin sense) and I'll post my also non-regex solution.

Comment: @Fan Is the `type-x` class always the first in the class list? If so, you can string replace `class=“type-x ` with `type=“x” class=“`.

Comment: Thats was my approach too @DakotaMethvin. Though I use `replaceAll()` method instead of changing the DOM

Comment: not always the first class entry .. lol  @Dakota Methvin

Comment: Well if its not the first, then that changes things *a lot*. The entire before "class" string will have to be tokenized.

Comment: Here’s [the pattern](https://regex101.com/r/myJg4l/1) I would go with to find your class: `(?<=class=")(?:[A-Za-z0-9\- ]*?)(type-[A-Za-z0-9\-]+)(?:[A-Za-z0-9\- ]*)(?=")`. Should be pretty easy from there to drop the class and add the attribute.

Answer (score 2):

**This isn't the solution. Just offers some insights on text parsing this problem without regex. As the OP did mention a possible non-regex solution.** Also this answer was posted during a very long comment session, and as such requirements changed.

This solution (in like fashion of @DakotaMethvin's) also attempts to solve it without regex, and as well, resides on a more exact pattern match with `class="type-`. As such the following code will indeed break (logically) if that's not the match.

However in light of FanCheung's more recent comment `[type-x] not always the first class entry`, I'm only posting this answer because I already started on posting it.

```js
function replaceIt( s, sentinel ) {
    // sentinel: e.g. class="type-
    if (sentinel) {
    
    }
    else sentinel = 'class="type-';
    
    return s.replaceAll(sentinel , function( match, offset ) {
        
        // get the position of the whitespace after "type-c"
        nextSpace = s.indexOf(" ", offset);
        
        // extract the "type" up until and excluding the "next space"
        typeVar = s.substring( offset + sentinel.length, nextSpace);
        
        // get the position of the 2nd double quote char 
        nextDoubleQuote = s.indexOf("\"", nextSpace);
        
        // extract the new "class" names e.g. red blue
        newClass = s.substring( nextSpace + 1, nextDoubleQuote);
        
        // create the replacement string. Also something must be done with the leftover chars; prepend them with 'data-source'.
        replacement = 'type="' + typeVar + '" class="' + newClass +'" data-source="'; 
        
        // debugging code
        console.log( match + ": " + offset + ": " + typeVar + ": " + newClass);
        
        return replacement;
    });
    
}

console.log( replaceIt( '<div class="type-c red blue">') );
```

But as noted on recent developments on what I noted on `The entire before "class" string will have to be tokenized.` So this solution only works if "type-" is the 1st class.

Comment: @FanCheung Yes thank you too. Was just bout to go back to my excessive non-regex (I did) .. I appreciate it: some tweaks on that non-regex, like 5 deletions of code and 5 additions. Okay really but helps to realize regex is superior in many (or some) cases. Glad you got your answer tho.

Comment: ya same here.  gonna do some more learning, seems very useful in refactoring